# ESLint unused var error with Vue script + setup

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint, prettier

I'm getting the error of **@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars** rule because of the "test" var in this component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const test: Ref<string> = ref('test')
</script>

<template lang="pug">
h2.title-medium.blue Home {{ test }}
input.input-border.input-base(v-model='test')
</template>
```

My .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  },
  extends: ['@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript', 'plugin:prettier/recommended'],
  plugins: [],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        trailingComma: 'all',
        tabWidth: 2,
        semi: false,
        singleQuote: true,
        bracketSpacing: true,
        eslintIntegration: true,
        printWidth: 120,
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this error in scripts without disabling the rule for the whole configuration?

Comment: Try swapping `extends`, nuxt is likely to override that rule for Vue files with accordinate vue-eslint rule

Comment: Tried but doesn't work